# Using SharpCifs.Std or SharpCifs.smb in a Unity UWP app

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, uwp, smb

I'm still fairly new to Unity and UWP app development, I need to retrieve models stored in a remote SMB share drive which requires authentication.

For the authentication, I've tried using the library SharpCifs.Std, but the Unity editor seems unable to read it, with the error, "the type or namespace name 'Std' does not exist in the namespace 'SharpCifs' (are you missing an assembly reference?)",

The following link http://sharpcifsstd.dobes.jp/, states that the .Net 4.6 framework is required for this library, and from what I understand, Unity is compatible with the .Net 4.6 framework (In Unity, Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Configuration -> Api Compatibility Level* -> .Net 4.x).

I've tried importing the library using Nuget Package Manager, both in Visual Studio and Unity itself, but unfortunately to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.